# Retrieve and print section of different data.frames within a loop

Tags: r

I have 100 data frames with name pattern `product_<region>`. These names are stored in vector `names`.

I would like to inspect them, but I don't want to type `print(product_<region>, n = 10)` 100 times.

I've tried

```
for (name in names) {
  print(paste0("product_", name), n = 10)
}
```

But that doesn't work because the output of `paste0()` is a string - it's not the data frame itself.

How can I retrieve the data frame using its name as a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Issues

1. Avoid using `names` as it conflicts with the `names(x)`.
2. Use `get(x)` to retrieve a variable from a text string.
3. Lastly,  `print()` does *not* have a `n=` parameter. Instead, use `head(x)` to see the `data.frame`'s first `n = 6L` observations (or `tail(x)` for the last `n = 6L`).

The use of the `print(x, n=10)` as a result is then triggering:

> Error in print.default(m, ..., quote = quote, right = right) :
>
> invalid 'na.print' specification

### Suggested Solution

```
for (region in regions) {
  print(head(get(paste0("product_", region)), n = 10))
}
```

### Test Data

Generate some sample data:

```
regions = c("chicago","detroit")

set.seed(11)

for(region in regions){
  d = data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10))
  assign(paste0("product_",region), d)
}
```

**Output:**

**Data Set 1:**

```
             a          b
1  -1.63651631  0.7898706
2   0.02038144 -0.2299939
3   0.89174268 -0.8185025
4  -0.87274968  0.4997342
5   0.89005083  0.1591923
6  -0.34387435  0.5426264
7  -2.18678137 -0.1566451
8   0.88005818  0.4387933
9   0.72385656  1.4878706
10  0.21985268  0.0601651
```

**Data Set 2:**

```
            a          b
1  -0.8490129  0.4534761
2   2.3396931 -0.1234337
3  -0.1212030 -0.7630968
4  -1.9502074  0.2282701
5   0.5387115  1.1194619
6   1.6935148  0.1565732
7  -0.7909682 -0.6887721
8  -1.0752606  0.4529496
9  -0.6078751 -1.0675467
10  0.7544017  0.4015651
```